# python: insert comma delimiter between words that are stuck together in a string with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a column in a table similar to the following.

| tags |
| --- |
| Large AcreageOcean IslandTurn KeyIncome Potential |
| Ocean IslandSeasonalMainland Lot |
| Lake IslandSeasonalTurn KeyIncome Potential |

I need to split the strings in the table so that it looks like this

| tags |
| --- |
| Large Acreage,Ocean Island,Turn Key,Income Potential |
| Ocean Island,Seasonal,Mainland Lot |
| Lake Island,Seasonal,Turn Key,Income Potential |

I thought a regex command like `re.sub(r'([a-z][A-Z])', ',', <string>)` could work but that code results in

`'Large Acreag,cean Islan,urn Ke,ncome Potential'`

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *two* capturing groups in the expression and *two* backreferences in replacement:

```py
re.sub(r'([a-z])([A-Z])', r'\1,\2', <string>)
```

If it is in Pandas:

```
df['tags'] = df['tags'].str.replace(r'([a-z])([A-Z])', r'\1,\2', regex=True)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/8g4tHn/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
```